# Commandline report Generation using Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I would like to automate the entire report generation process using Pentaho report designer using *commandline*. Is it possible to achieve it in Pentaho?

Input = results data stored in a database
Output = Generate report ( in the form of chart for ex) using Report designer

Thanks
Kelly

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you dont want to use a BI server at all, is to use the Pentaho Report output step in PDI/Kettle. This is great for scheduled jobs.  The advantage of this over running schedules in the BI server is that you can cron them, and then if the BI server is down your reports will still run!  i.e. it's a lot more reliable.

Comment: Interesting tip also for me. From what PDI version it is available?

Comment: I'm not sure. 4.2 I think, but dont quote me on that!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wget and submit URL of xaction.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue [*As a reporting user, I want to be able to run reports via a simple GUI tool or via the command line without a GUI*](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PRD-2368) open since Dec 2009.

According to [*Command line tool to run reports*](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-433) it's not planned as of Mar 2014.